# Magento supee 6788 on 1.9.1.1, error applying patch

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-6788, ce-1.9.1.1

I've got the following error while applying the patch on 1.9.1.1:

```
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej
```

I've doubled checked from a fresh copy that the file was not edited.

The .htaccess files are the same.

Any ideas? Thanks!

This is the full log:

```
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file .htaccess
Hunk #1 succeeded at 175 (offset -32 lines).
patching file .htaccess.sample
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
patching file cron.php
patching file errors/processor.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 463 with fuzz 2.
patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
patching file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

My admin.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
{
    /**
     * Fetch default path
     */
    public function fetchDefault()
    {
        // set defaults
        $d = explode('/', $this->_getDefaultPath());
        $this->getFront()->setDefault(array(
            'module'     => !empty($d[0]) ? $d[0] : '',
            'controller' => !empty($d[1]) ? $d[1] : 'index',
            'action'     => !empty($d[2]) ? $d[2] : 'index'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get router default request path
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getDefaultPath()
    {
        return (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/web/default/admin');
    }

    /**
     * dummy call to pass through checking
     *
     * @return unknown
     */
    protected function _beforeModuleMatch()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * checking if we installed or not and doing redirect
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _afterModuleMatch()
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * We need to have noroute action in this router
     * not to pass dispatching to next routers
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _noRouteShouldBeApplied()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether URL for corresponding path should use https protocol
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _shouldBeSecure($path)
    {
        return substr((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/web/unsecure/base_url'), 0, 5) === 'https'
            || Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('web/secure/use_in_adminhtml', Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
                && substr((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/web/secure/base_url'), 0, 5) === 'https';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current secure url
     *
     * @param Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCurrentSecureUrl($request)
    {
        return Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
            ->getBaseUrl('link', true) . ltrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
    }

    /**
     * Emulate custom admin url
     *
     * @param string $configArea
     * @param bool $useRouterName
     */
    public function collectRoutes($configArea, $useRouterName)
    {
        if ((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_USE_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH)) {
            $customUrl = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_PATH);
            $xmlPath = Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ADMINHTML_ROUTER_FRONTNAME;
            if ((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode($xmlPath) != $customUrl) {
                Mage::getConfig()->setNode($xmlPath, $customUrl, true);
            }
        }
        parent::collectRoutes($configArea, $useRouterName);
    }
}
```

The patch is right: `PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh`
I copied the downloader folder too.

UPDATE:

Isn't the patch wrong?
Patch: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-45-55.sh has this following code:

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
index 54701ef..c798a03 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
@@ -131,6 +131,29 @@ class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin extends Mage_Core_Controller_Vari
     }

     /**
+     * Add module definition to routes.
+     *
+     * @param string $frontName
+     * @param mixed $moduleName
+     * @param string $routeName
+     * @return $this
+     */
+    public function addModule($frontName, $moduleName, $routeName)
+    {
+        $isExtensionsCompatibilityMode = (bool)(string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
+            'default/admin/security/extensions_compatibility_mode'
+        );
+        $configRouterFrontName = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
+            Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ADMINHTML_ROUTER_FRONTNAME
+        );
+        if ($isExtensionsCompatibilityMode || ($frontName == $configRouterFrontName)) {
+            return parent::addModule($frontName, $moduleName, $routeName);
+        } else {
+            return $this;
+        }
+    }
+
+    /**
      * Check if current controller instance is allowed in current router.
      * 
      * @param Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $controllerInstance
```

But in magento base installation of `magento-1.9.1.1-2015-04-30-12-49-08.zip`
the file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php` does not have this code:

```
/**
 * Check if current controller instance is allowed in current router.
 * 
 * @param Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $controllerInstance
```

If I insert

```
 /**
 * Check if current controller instance is allowed in current router.
 * 
 * @param Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action $controllerInstance
 * @return boolean
 */
protected function _validateControllerInstance($controllerInstance)
{
    return true;
}
```

then it works.

Comment: are you able to upload your `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php`. Just confirming you downloaded the right patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SUPEE-6788 requires all previous patches to be applied. You're seeing this error because a previous patch hasn't been applied. Check what's in app/etc/applied.patches.list and compare it with the Magento patch list

Comment: indeed it was an issue with a previous patch

Comment: Can I check somewhere wich files has been modified in each patch?

Comment: @JonZangitu you can see which files/lines are modified in each patch if you open the patch file in a text editor (Gedit, Notepad++, rather than Notepad)

Comment: I was hoping something more comfortable, any changelog file or something like that, but thank you anyway!

Comment: @JonZangitu that patch file acts as a change log, in that it shows which files have changed and where.

Comment: Had the same problem. I had to install all the patches that were to be installed till the last patch.

Comment: Which patch specifically fixed this issue? I am running into the same issue and I think it is SUPEE-5994

Comment: I confirmed that this was my missing patch. When I had attempted to apply SUPEE-5944, I did not notice that it failed. It failed due to having been applied previously incorrectly.

Comment: If anyone needs this, my issue was specifically with applying PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.11.0.0_to_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-05-14-07-04-12.sh on Magento EE 1.13.0.0